# Como implementar SQLite de ngCordova en ionic

Tags: angularjs, ionic, cordova, ng-cordova

Tratando de implementar el plugin ***SQLite*** de ***ngCordova***, me he encontrado con la confusión de como implementar el plugin, debido a que en la pagina oficial aparece de una forma, y en el repositorio de github de otra.

[Plugin ngCordova](http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/sqlite/)

[Repositorio GitHub](https://github.com/litehelpers/Cordova-sqlite-storage)

Aqui esta el codigo

### Ejemeplo 1

En este ejemplo no ocurre ningún error pero la base de datos no funciona, no ocurre nada no guarda nada.

```
angular.module('unicesarApp', ['ionic', 'historialApp'])
       .controller('formulario', formulario)
       .service('obtenerDatos', obtenerDatos)
       .config(config);

formulario.$inject = ['$scope', 'obtenerDatos', '$state', '$timeout'];

function formulario($scope, obtenerDatos, $state, $timeout){

    $scope.login = function(){


        var datos, datosRespuesta;

        datos = {
            Usuario: $scope.usuariotxt,
            Password: $scope.passwordtxt
        };

        if(datos.Usuario == undefined && datos.Password == undefined){

            $scope.respuesta = "Los campos estan vacios";

        }else{                

            $state.go('Loading');
            //$scope.respuesta = "Solicitando informacion";

            obtenerDatos.Autenticacion(datos).then(function(response) {

              if(response.data) {

                datosRespuesta = response.data;

                  if (datosRespuesta === "Usuario no registrado" || 
                      datosRespuesta === "Contraseña incorrecta") {

                      $timeout(function() {
                          $scope.respuesta = datosRespuesta;
                          $state.go('login');
                        }, 2000);


                  } else {        

                        if (datosRespuesta.estudiante){

                            console.log(datosRespuesta.estudiante);

                            var db, Perfil;

                            db = window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase({name: "unicesar.db", createFromLocation: 1});

                            Perfil = datosRespuesta.estudiante;

                            db.transaction(function(tx){

                                var crearTablaPerfil, queryInsertar, queryConsulta;


                                crearTablaPerfil = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Estudiante(Cedula integer primary key, Nombre text,   Apellido text, Rol integer, Facultad text, Programa text, Semestre integer)";

                                queryInsertar = "INSERT INTO Estudiante(Cedula, Nombre, Apellido, Rol, Facultad, Programa, Semestre)  VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";

                                queryConsulta = "SELECT * FROM Estudiante";

                                tx.executeSql(crearTablaPerfil);

                                tx.execute(db, queryInsertar, [Perfil.CeduEstu, Perfil.NombEstu, Perfil.ApelEstu,    Perfil.RolEstu, Perfil.FacuEstu, Perfil.ProgEstu, Perfil.Semestre]);

                                tx.executeSql(queryConsulta, [], function(tx, result) {

                                    var row;

                                     if(result.rows.length > 0) {

                                         row = result.rows.item(0);

                                         alert("Datos:", row.Cedula +" "+ row.Nombre +" "+ row.Apellido +" "+ row.Rol +" "+ row.Facultad +" "+ row.Programa +" "+ row.Semestre);

                                     };  

                                }, 

                                function(e){
                                    console.log("error: "+e.message);
                                });

                            }); 

                            $state.go('Loading');

                            $timeout(function() {
                                $state.go(datosRespuesta.estudiante ? 'menuestu' : 'menuprof');
                            }, 3000);      

                    }else {

                         console.log(response.status);
                         $scope.respuesta = "Error en la solicitud";
                         $state.go('login');

                        };     



                 };

             };

          });

        };

    };
};
```

### Ejemplo 2

Utilizando esta forma, se genera un error que no me muestra el navegador, solo que al compilar y obtener la apk, y luego instalarla, la vista principal de la aplicación aparece en blanco, por ende no funciona la app.

```
angular.module('unicesarApp', ['ionic', 'historialApp', 'ngCordova'])
       .controller('formulario', formulario)
       .service('obtenerDatos', obtenerDatos)
       .config(config);

formulario.$inject = ['$scope', 'obtenerDatos', '$state', '$timeout', '$cordovaSQLite'];

function formulario($scope, obtenerDatos, $state, $timeout, $cordovaSQLite){

    $scope.login = function(){


        var datos, datosRespuesta;

        datos = {
            Usuario: $scope.usuariotxt,
            Password: $scope.passwordtxt
        };

        if(datos.Usuario == undefined && datos.Password == undefined){

            $scope.respuesta = "Los campos estan vacios";

        }else{                

            $state.go('Loading');
            //$scope.respuesta = "Solicitando informacion";

            obtenerDatos.Autenticacion(datos).then(function(response) {

              if(response.data) {

                datosRespuesta = response.data;

                  if (datosRespuesta === "Usuario no registrado" || 
                      datosRespuesta === "Contraseña incorrecta") {

                      $timeout(function() {
                          $scope.respuesta = datosRespuesta;
                          $state.go('login');
                        }, 2000);


                  } else {        

                        if (datosRespuesta.estudiante){

                            console.log(datosRespuesta.estudiante);

                            var db, Perfil, row, crearTablaPerfil, guardarPerfil, consultaPerfil; 

                            Perfil = datosRespuesta.estudiante;

                            db = $cordovaSQLite.openDB({ name: "unicesar.db" });

                            crearTablaPerfil = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Estudiante(Cedula integer primary key, Nombre text,   Apellido text, Rol integer, Facultad text, Programa text, Semestre integer)";

                            guardarPerfil = "INSERT INTO Estudiante(Cedula, Nombre, Apellido, Rol, Facultad, Programa, Semestre)  VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";

                            consultaPerfil = "SELECT * FROM Estudiante";

                            $cordovaSQLite.execute(db, crearTablaPerfil);

                            $cordovaSQLite.execute(db, guardarPerfil, [Perfil.CeduEstu, Perfil.NombEstu, Perfil.ApelEstu,    Perfil.RolEstu, Perfil.FacuEstu, Perfil.ProgEstu, Perfil.Semestre]);

                            $cordovaSQLite.execute(db, consultaPerfil).then(function(result){

                                if(result.rows.length > 0) {

                                    row = result.rows.item(0);

                                    alert("Datos:", row.Cedula +" "+ row.Nombre +" "+ row.Apellido +" "+ row.Rol +" "+ row.Facultad +" "+ row.Programa +" "+ row.Semestre);


                                $state.go('Loading');

                                $timeout(function() {
                                    $state.go(datosRespuesta.estudiante ? 'menuestu' : 'menuprof');
                                }, 3000); 



                    }else {

                         console.log(response.status);
                         $scope.respuesta = "Error en la solicitud";
                         $state.go('login');

                        };     



                 };

             };

          });

        };

    };
};
```

Si alguien sabe cual podría ser el error se lo agradecería de ante mano.

Comment: A que te refieres con que el plugin está de una forma en el repositorio de github y de otra en la página oficial? Podrías incluir esos links en tu pregunta?

Comment: @devconcept gracias por preguntar, allí están, en la pagina de ngCordova pues muestra como se implementa, pero al hacerlo, en el navegador no me muestra ninguno que es lo mas raro, debido a que cualquier cosa errónea que haga me manda error, pero esta vez, lo otro podría ser, que exista conflicto entre ngCordova y Crosswalk

Comment: @PedroMiguelPimientaMorales prueba a depurar mediante Chrome, con tu dispositivo con la depuración USB activada, conectalo al PC y en Chrome abre la url: chrome://inspect, ahí podrás ver la consola y ver si se está mostrando algún log o error.

Comment: Ok, gracias @jjimenez, sabes como hacer esto mismo pero como el genymotion e instalar la apk en el emulador?

Answer (score 1):

Primero el proyecto de **ngCordova** ya no esta siendo soportado por lo cual a veces esta desactulizado respecto a la documentacion oficial.

Con **SQLite** ocurre esto, la documentacion de ngCordova no esta actulizada, el plugin recientemente hizo algunos cambios, para que funcione deberias crear la base de datos de esta manera:

```
 DB = $cordovaSQLite.openDB({
  name: 'app.db',
  location: 'default',
  iosDatabaseLocation: 'Library'
});
```

Estos dos ultimos parametros **location** y **iosDatabaseLocation**, no estan en la documentacion de ngCordova pero en la documentacion del plugin  si estan y son obligatorias, esto hace que simplemente no se cree la base de datos por lo cual podria ser la causa de tu problema.

Bye!